# How to convert 2d array of integers into 8-bit greyscale bitmap?

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin, bitmap

I need to convert a two dimensional array of integers (containing values from 0 to 255) to 8bit greyscale bitmap. I'm using [IndexedBitmap](https://github.com/badpx/IndexedBitmap) library, which is supposed to support this:

> This library can be used to create 8BPP(8-bits per pixel) indexed
>   color bitmap, so it takes up storage space is a quarter of the same
>   dimension 32-bit bitmap(like ARGB8888).

This is my code:

```
fun convertTwoDimensionalArrayToBitmap(inputArray: Array<IntArray>): Bitmap {
    val height = inputArray.size
    val width = inputArray[0].size
    val byteArray = ByteArray(height * width)
    var index = 0
    for (i in 0 until height) {
        for (j in 0 until width) {
            val byte = inputArray[i][j].toByte()
            byteArray[index] = byte
            index++
        }
    }

    val palette = PaletteFactory.getGrayPalette()
    return IndexBitmapFactory.createBitmap(
            byteArray, palette, 0, 0, width, height, false)
}
```

And I'm getting following error when I try to use it (in this case I'm passing 256 by 256 2d array):

```
> 2018-11-28 16:03:46.913
> 23154-23175/com.my.package.test D/IndexBitmap: Raw
> buffer length = 66596 2018-11-28 16:03:46.913
> 23154-23175/com.my.package.test D/Bitmap:
> Bitmap_createFromParcel: Serialized SkColorSpace is larger than
> expected: 256 bytes 2018-11-28 16:03:46.913
> 23154-23175/com.my.package.test W/System.err:
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to unparcel Bitmap 2018-11-28
> 16:03:46.914 23154-23175/com.my.package.test
> W/System.err:     at
> android.graphics.Bitmap$1.createFromParcel(Bitmap.java:1781)
> 2018-11-28 16:03:46.914
> 23154-23175/com.my.package.test W/System.err:     at
> android.graphics.Bitmap$1.createFromParcel(Bitmap.java:1772)
> 2018-11-28 16:03:46.914
> 23154-23175/com.my.package.test W/System.err:     at
> com.badpx.indexbitmap.graphics.IndexBitmapFactory.createBitmap(IndexBitmapFactory.java:97)
> 2018-11-28 16:03:46.914
> 23154-23175/com.my.package.test W/System.err:     at
> com.badpx.indexbitmap.graphics.IndexBitmapFactory.createBitmap(IndexBitmapFactory.java:78)
```

Am I using this library in a wrong way? Is there any other way of converting 2d array to 8bit bitmap on Android?

Comment: Has any one found solution on this ?